# Create a new folder in TFS web interface

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

In my TFS project repository URL I need to create a new folder without using Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: Just click on the "TeamSetup" node in the tree (left pane); choose "New" -> "Folder".

Comment: No there is no option to choose "New" -> "Folder", the version I am using is "Version 15.117.26714.0"

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, it looks like you use TFS 2017 so you need to install the [Folder Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.FolderManagement) extension to add this feature.

After you install it you can create a folder in this way:

[image]

Comment: How to install folder management extension. Kindly guide me on the same.

Comment: Click on the link, download the extension, then go to the TFS settings -> extensions and install it.

Comment: I am getting the response as "This extension does not support the version of the Server you are currently using. See Works With for supported Server versions."Works with
Team Foundation Server 2015 update 4
Team Foundation Server 2017 RTM
Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 1
Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 2" My version was compatible but still it is showing not supported for your version.

Comment: Is there anyway to create folder without a file ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you are working on TFS2017 update2 version with  Git repo.

This is by designed. You could not add folders in remote repo through web portal directly.

It's only support for Azure DevOps Service (previous VSTS) and Team Foundation Server 2018, or higher. As shayki already pointed out, in previous TFS version, you have to use  Folder Management.

Make sure you are following these instructions https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions for TFS on-prem.

If you just want to add folders without Visual Studio, suggest you directly create folders in local repository and then use gitbash command to **push your local repo to remote repo**.

Another choice is upgrading your TFS version to 2018 and above.

Answer (score 0):

As Git doesn't support versioning on empty folders you're not able to create an empty folder. you could however create a file "newfolder/.gitkeep" in order for the folder to be created

Comment: No it is not working. Unable to create a new file with name "newfolder/.gitkeep"

Comment: sorry about that, though that should work. but i didn't have an on-prem environment to validate :(